# How to NOT Terminate Batch Job

Tags: command-line, terminal, powershell, batch

in my power shell command prompt when I run a command and pressing `ctrl` + `c` a message appears asking for `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?` no matter if I enter `Y`, or `N` or `n`, it terminates the job.

My question is how can I cancel terminating and keep the application running? (because it seems that prompt is useless)

See below screen shot

[image]

Comment: How do you know the job is terminating? Maybe it just reached the end of the script.

Comment: @Appleoddity I am running angular app, so if I don't press ctrl+c it's still running, and after that it will be stopped

Comment: The prompt is from `cmd.exe` when you press `Ctrl+C` to cancel execution of a batch file (shell script). This means that somewhere you are running a `.cmd` or `.bat` file, which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In batch you can block CTRL+C signal using the `BREAK` command.

For PowerShell, you can capute that signal using a `try...catch` block, as described in [this page](http://sushihangover.blogspot.com/2012/03/powershell-using-try-finally-block-to.html).

Comment: Try `break/?`, it says "It has no effect under Windows." :-(

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a bit philistine, but I've always had the best results stopping scripts by holding down the CTRL key and rapidly alternating between CTRL-C and CTRL-BREAK.

That trick has gotten me out of TONS of situations over the decades where neither CTRL-C mashing nor CTRL-BREAK mashing were sufficient.